# Unit testing fetchtype lazy

Tags: hibernate, spring

I have the following code:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Foo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
private Collection<Bar> bars;
}

@Entity
public class Bar {

@ManyToOne
private Foo foo;
}
```

I am trying to unit test the DAO class.

```
@Transactionl
public class TestDao {

@Test
public void testLazy (){
Foo foo = dao.findById(1);
assertTrue(foo.getBars() != null && !foo.getBars().isEmpty())
//SOME CODE THAT I NEED YOUR HELP WITH
assertTrue(foo.getBars() == null || foo.getBars().isEmpty())
}

@Test
test1...

@Test
test2...

@Test
test3...

}
```

I need help figuring out what //SOME CODE THAT I NEED YOUR HELP WITH
needs to be for this test to pass.

Thanks for the help
Netta

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to post that as an answer. What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to test if the `bars` collection is loaded lazily on the first access to the collection?

I did something similar by implementing two tests. One tests that checks the correct size of the collection if the data is loaded lazily and one test that checks for the specific exception that is thrown if you access the collection after it has been detached.

Something similar to this (JPA/Hibernate + TestNG)

```
@Test
public void testLazyLoading() {

  // load foo
  Foo foo = dao.findById(1);

  // check correct size
  assertTrue(foo.getBars() != null && !foo.getBars().isEmpty())

}

@Test(expectedExceptions=LazyInitializationException.class)
public void testLazyInitializationException() {

  // load foo
  Foo foo = dao.findById(1);

  // detach all instances
  entityManager.clear();

  // will throw LazyInitializationException
  foo.getBars().size();

}
```

Comment: @Netta: If you tried this and it didn't work, then your lazy loading isn't working. Make careful note of what you call before the clear()/evict(). Doing anything to the collection, like calling isEmpty(), will initialize it, and then evicting the owning instance won't do any good.

Comment: I tried hibernateTemplate.evict(foo) and hibernateTemplate.clear(). The list is still loaded. Is it possible that the object is being retrieved again because the session is still active?

Comment: Amazing. Using this entityManager.clear() has cleared all my doubts as I'm able to test lazy loading things and can be sure I've done right things to make it work as expected.